# how to make nginx work with html5mode and images

Tags: angularjs, nginx, html5mode

I've been googling how to enable html5 for angular apps using nginx.
and the majority of posts I found recommend using

**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;**

I've been running some tests and everything seems to be working fine with navigation.

Excepts when I insert an image with a valid path it works fine
but if i insert an image with an invalid path it returns a 200 instead of 404.
or if i try.

**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html=404;**

When insert an image with an invalid path it returns a 500 instead of 404.

how can I enable html5 mode for routes only, and not affecting images?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding a new location route for assets

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

thanks to @szarapka for giving me the answer

https://gist.github.com/szarapka/05ba804dfd1c10ad47bf